# Aggregated Javadoc on Maven Central

Tags: maven, javadoc, maven-central

I have a project, which is split into a number of Maven sub-modules. All of these are hosted on Maven Central, including the parent POM file.

As part of the build, I produce an aggregated Javadoc JAR for all of the sub-modules (as well as Javadoc for each individual sub-modules). I want to share that aggregated so that people can refer to that single JAR rather than having to refer to multiple different Javadoc JARs.

Is it acceptable/common practice to upload that aggregated Javadoc JAR to Maven Central as the Javadoc for the parent project? Or is that frowned upon for some reason (and if so, what are the alternatives)? I don't recall seeing a project doing it before (although I must admit I wasn't looking), so thought I'd check before breaking with convention.

Comment: Without knowing convention here, "people" rarely refer to Javadoc JARs nowadays. It's the IDEs doing this, e.g. when downloading dependencies, they also check for Source and Javadoc JARs to display documentation inline. With that in mind, there would be no advantage of additionally publishing an aggregated JAR.

Comment: The advantage is that I want to make use of the http://javadoc.io website, but at the moment it is splitting my documentation across the different modules. If I were to make an aggregated JAR available via Maven Central somehow, then there would be a single place on Javadoc.io for all my documentation.

Comment: Oh, nice site, didn't know it yet. Hope you'll get a useful answer (I think it shouldn't be a problem, but that's not very authoritative).